# which is all they need in

Tags: meaning

> In the week since Prime Minister Lee Wan-koo declared a war on
>   corruption in business circles, prosecutors have launched an
>   investigation into Posco Engineering and Construction (E&C) for
>   alleged slush funds overseas and companies that made investments in
>   line with the Lee Myung-bak administration’s resource diplomacy push.
>
> Worries are spreading quickly among major companies that they may be
>   next, **which is all they need in** a stuck-in-the rut economy with
>   falling oil prices, a weak yen and the threat of deflation.

I'm not sure about the meaning of phrase "which is all they need in".
Isn't this an irony, because I think the last thing major companies expect would be the government's investigation into them.

Comment: The phrase is just _which is all they need_. _in_ is part of the prepositional phrase _in a stuck-in-the-rut economy_.

Comment: It's just a sarcastic inversion - in context, what it *really* means is *this is the **last** thing they need* (they don't need it at all - in fact it's a *very bad* thing for them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*which is all they need* is an idiom used when someone or something is already in a bad situation, and an additional problem (described before this) is given to them. *in* is the preposition that links to a description of the existing state.

So this is saying that major companies are already in trouble because of the bad economy, and they're worried that the investigation will spread to them and make things harder.